# Number of spectral lines from $n_2$ to $n_1$

Tags: permutations, combinations, chemistry

> When electrons de-excite from higher energy level $\left(n_{2}\right)$ to lower energy level $\left(n_{1}\right)$ in atomic sample, then number of spectral line observed in the spectrum
> $$
> =\frac{\left(\mathrm{n}_{2}-\mathrm{n}_{1}\right)\left(\mathrm{n}_{2}-\mathrm{n}_{1}+1\right)}{2}
> $$

According to [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-to-find-the-total-number-of-spectral-lines-during-electron-transition-from-one-level-to-another), this is derived from permatuation & combination. Can you please help me the derivation from permatuation & combination

Comment: I don't know chemistry, but it may be helpful to know that this is the same as ${n_2 - n_1 + 1 \choose 2}$, or equivalently the sum $$1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + (n_2 - n_1)$$

Comment: As mentioned above comment, we can just help you to recall the formula for the sum of first $n$ natural numbers. Indeed, $1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$. In your case $n=n_2-n_1$. In the language of combination, it means you are choosing $2$ things out $n_2-n_1$ choices and total number of such possibility is the number $\binom{(n_2-n_1)+1}{2}$

Comment: I hope you can your answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109286/formulas-for-the-number-of-spectral-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k=n_2-n_1$. the number of states between (and including) energy levels $n_1$ and $n_2$ is $k+1$. thus the number of spectral lines is the number of ways of choosing 2 states from the $k+1$ states, which is $${k+1\choose 2}=\frac{(n_2-n_1+1)(n_2-n_1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

When electron excited to n state. It can be dexcited to $n-1, n-2. n-3 , ......... 2,1.$
So total number of spectral lines in this case is$$ 1+2+3+......+(n-1)+ n = \frac {n(n+1)}{2}.$$
In your case $ n= n_2 - n_1$.

Comment: the electron is excited to state $n_2$, not $n_2-n_1$.